# Best way to get parent object in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  'use strict';
  var Image_Selector = function () {};

  Image_Selector.prototype.init = function ($wrapper) {
    this.$select_btn = $wrapper.find('.set-image-btn');

    this.$select_btn.click(function (e) {
      console.log(this);    //jquery object
      console.log(e);       //just the event

      // What's the best way to call 'open_image_selector()' here?
    });
  }; // init

  Image_Selector.prototype.open_image_selector = function () {
    console.log (this);
    // do awesome stuff
  };
}); // doc rdy
</script>
```

What's the best way to call `open_image_selector` inside the `jquery.click` function?

Comment: @FelixKling thx for the reference. Although I got an answer from Sann that doesn't require an extra var.

Comment: Well, it was not clear whether you want to keep `this` to refer to the DOM element. FWIW, there are tons of duplicates for this question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method

```
 this.$select_btn.click(function (e) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(e);
    //Calling `open_image_selector`
    this.open_image_selector()
 }.bind(this));
```

Bind `this` to your click listener, so that `this` inside that function refers to the current instance of the `Image_Selector` object.

Answer (score 1):

`this` within the clcik handler is the DOM element that is clicked.

Cache your class `this` outside of the clcik handler so it is avaialable inside the handler. Can also use `$.proxy` to change context for the handler

```
Image_Selector.prototype.init = function ($wrapper) {

     var self=this;
    self.$select_btn = $wrapper.find('.set-image-btn');

    self.$select_btn.click(function (e) {
      console.log(self); /* should log "Image_Selector" object*/
       self.open_image_selector()  

    });
  }; // init
```

Comment: Upvote because it works

Comment: keep in mind that if you use `bind` and you want to manipulate actual button clciked( add a class, or change text for example) you lose context of the button instance